Customizing WooCommerce Category URLs to Use Names Instead of Slugs
Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I'm currently developing a WooCommerce store and have come across a unique requirement due to my integration with commercial management software. My setup utilizes category slugs as unique identifiers for synchronization purposes. However, for a more user-friendly and SEO-optimized URL structure, I wish to customize the URLs of categories and sub-categories to display their names instead of the slugs. It's important to clarify that this need only applies to category URLs, as the product URLs (which also use slugs) meet my requirements as is.
After researching and exploring the WooCommerce settings, specifically the "Product permalinks" section, I understand it primarily allows for slug-based customization (e.g., "/shop/%product_cat%/"). My initial searches on Stack Overflow and the WooCommerce documentation have not yielded a solution or plugin recommendation that addresses this specific scenario.
Here are the key points of my situation:
The necessity to maintain the use of slugs as IDs for external software integration.
The desire to have category and sub-category URLs reflect the category name for better readability and SEO, without altering the slug itself.
Looking for a recommendation on a plugin or custom code snippet that can facilitate this adjustment.
Before posting, I reviewed similar inquiries but found none that matched my exact circumstances, particularly regarding the need to preserve slugs for integration purposes while altering the URL appearance.
Can anyone provide insights, plugin recommendations, or code examples that would help achieve this URL customization? Any guidance on tackling this within WooCommerce's framework would be immensely appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance and expertise.

Hello everyone,
I wanted to share that I've found a solution to my earlier question regarding customizing WooCommerce category URLs to use category names instead of slugs, without altering the slugs used for synchronization with my commercial management software.
After exploring various options, I discovered that the "Permalink Manager Pro" plugin provides the functionality needed to achieve this. Here's the process I followed to implement the customization:

Navigate to the plugin settings: Settings -> Permalink Manager.
In the "Permastructures" tab, locate the section for taxonomies and select the option "Use actual titles instead of WordPress slugs". This setting allows the plugin to use the actual titles for generating URLs instead of the default WordPress behavior that uses slugs.
Then, go to "Tools" -> "Permalink Manager" -> "Tools" section.
In the "Regenerate/reset" tool, set the Mode to "Regenerate custom permalinks".
For "Select content types", choose "Taxonomies", then specifically select "Product categories" from the list to target the WooCommerce category URLs.
Finally, click on "Regenerate" to update the permalinks according to the new settings.

This process regenerated the category permalinks to reflect the actual titles of each category instead of the slugs, while leaving the original slugs intact for backend purposes.
I hope this solution helps anyone facing a similar challenge. A big thank you to the community for your support and suggestions.

It's always recommended to check the woocommerce documentation. Glad you managed to figure it out and I am sure someone else will find your adequate answer useful.
